# javac does not find classpath

Tags: linux, servlets, tomcat7, javac

I am attempting to recompile a Java class via the command line. It was built by a team mate using his eclipse setup and as I do not have eclipse I am using `javac`. It attempts to import on of our own packages on another branch of the package tree:

```
import my.custom.class.subclass.Functionality;
```

I am trying to compile `src/my/custom/class/NewServlet.java`.

I keep getting errors indicating that the package does not exist. How should I specify the classpath for a package that is not in a JAR anywhere?

If it is relevant, I am running `javac 1.7.0_25` on Ubuntu 12.04.2 Server (64-bit) installed from the `openjdk-7-jdk` package.

Comment: Even if he uses Eclipse, can you check if there is an Ant or Maven build file?

Comment: @Thilo I will, but surely there is a sequence of commands in this build file that I can enter manually as well...

Comment: Well, I missed your point. But thanks for mentioning it.